# Guidance with Stripe Payment Logic Implementation

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments, logic

I am working on a **React JSX** project and I am at the part where I am working on Stripe Payment implementation (*First time setting up a payment system*).

Although I have a working system I am still not confident in the LOGIC of the implementation.

Currently, the payment system is setup as so that when the USER makes a successful payment they are given access to the Form to create a post.

I have made this awful chart but I hope it kinda gives you an idea of my current logic.

[image]

Is there a **better logic** that will increase security which is my main concern.

*I am not looking for code. I just want to ask people who might have experience with setting up a **PAY FIRST TO POST** system.*

Thanks!